# How could I cast to DateTimeInterface from String?? Symfony Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, doctrine

My real problem is that I am sending an Ajax Jquery Request to an API of mine, the server response is 'Argument #1 of ::setDate() must be DateTimeInterface, string given'

I tried to cast but it was useless.

My Ajax at JQUERY:

```js
    $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/api/distribucion",
            data: JSON.stringify(dist),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("mesa " + response.id + " actualizada");
            }
        });
```

My API at PHP (Symfony's controller):

```php
    public function putDistribucion(ManagerRegistry $mr, Request $request): Response
    {
        $datos = json_decode($request->getContent());
        $datos = $datos->distribucion;
        // Cogemos el ID de el Distribucion a editar
        $id = $datos->id;
        // Obtenemos el Distribucion
        $distribucion = $mr->getRepository(Distribucion::class)->find($id);
        // Cambiamos todos sus campos
        $distribucion->setPosicionX($datos->pos_x);
        $distribucion->setPosicionY($datos->pos_y);
        $distribucion->setFecha($datos->fecha);
        $distribucion->setMesaId($datos->mesa_id);
        $distribucion->setAlias($datos->alias);
        $distribucion->setReservada($datos->reservada);

        $manager = $mr->getManager();
        try {
            // Lo mandamos a actualizar
            $manager->persist($distribucion);
            $manager->flush();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->json(['message' => $e->getMessage(), "Success" => false], 400);
        }

        # Creado con éxito => Devolvemos la ID
        return $this->json(
            [
                "message" => "Éxito al editar la distribucion " . $id,
                "Success" => true
            ],
            202 // Aceptado
        );
    }
```

The Object I'm sending:

[image: The console.log of the object sended]

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity `Distribucion` probably has a setter that look like this:

```php
public function setFecha(DateTimeInterface $fecha): self
    {
        $this->fecha = $fecha;

        return $this;
    }
```

The setter is typehinted with `DateTimeInterface` so you need to use a `DateTime` object and not a string.

You may create a DateTime easily with `DateTime::createFromFormat`

So `$distribucion->setFecha($datos->fecha);` will turn into something like:

```
$distribucion->setFecha(DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss.u', $datos->fecha));
```

You may want to verify the date format I used as the first parameter of `DateTime::createFromFormat`

> public static DateTime::createFromFormat(string $format, string $datetime, ?DateTimeZone $timezone = null)

Comment: It says `App\Entity\Distribucion::setFecha(): Argument #1 ($fecha) must be of type DateTimeInterface, bool given`

Comment: createFromFormat return false if the date is not created, verify the date format used and if `$datos->fecha` is the same format